# Resample dataframe quarterly but using different end months

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to sum the data for each month in my dataframe, but with a cumulative sum over each month of the quarter.  So the input is:

```
Index          Data
2017-02-05     10
2017-03-04     20
2017-06-20     40
```

This code works below:

```
cum_df = monthly_df.groupby(by=[monthly_df.index.quarter, monthly_df.index.year]).cumsum()
```

With the following output:

```
Index         Data
2017-02-28    10
2017-03-31    30
2017-04-31    0
2017-05-31    0
2017-06-30    40
```

However, I don't want the quarters to end in Mar/Jun/Sep/Dec but for a custom quarter end like Feb/May/Aug/Nov.  How can I change my code to work for custom quarter ends?

Comment: Share the sample input and expected output please.

Comment: Updated to show the input and output. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.Grouper(freq='anchored_offset')`, where `anchored_offset` is the desired "anchored offset" string from the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2017-02-01', end='2018-1-31', freq='W'))

# Label each Sunday with a 1
df[0] = 1

# Group by quarter with year ending in November ('Q-NOV'), but label each quarter
# with its start date ('QS-NOV')
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='QS-NOV')).sum()

             0
2017-02-01  13
2017-05-01  13
2017-08-01  13
2017-11-01  13
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think the freq='S-NOV' instead of 'QS-NOV', but otherwise it works great